# Cookiecutter-bonobo init failed

Tags: python, etl, cookiecutter, bonobo-etl

I am new to Stack Overflow so apologies if the structure of the question needs work.

I'm trying to create a new project in cookiecutter-bonobo on my Mac for the first time (recently installed anaconda3 to replace anaconda2, so am using python3). I am following these instructions https://www.bonobo-project.org/with/cookiecutter. So far, I have successfully installed cookiecutter and bonobo using pip:

```
pip install bonobo cookiecutter
```

but get an error when execute the following step in the command line:

```
bonobo init example-jobs
```

The error reads

```
CRIT:0001:root: Uncaught exception (in thread 140735648375616).
│ Traceback (most recent call last):
│   File "/Users/maxpaton/anaconda3/bin/bonobo", line 11, in <module>
│     sys.exit(entrypoint())
│   File "/Users/maxpaton/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bonobo/commands/__init__.py", line 59, in entrypoint
│     command(**parsed_args)
│   File "/Users/maxpaton/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bonobo/commands/init.py", line 74, in handle
│     self.create_file_from_template(template=template, filename=filename)
│   File "/Users/maxpaton/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bonobo/commands/init.py", line 24, in create_file_from_template
│     raise ValueError('Filenames should end with ".py".')
└ ValueError  Filenames should end with ".py".
```

The required result is for it to create a directory with certain helpful files in it. I found a very similar issue at https://github.com/python-bonobo/bonobo/issues/235, but the suggested solution doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Cookiecutter template has been deprecated and is not necessary anymore.

There are now two ways you can bootstrap ETL jobs:

- Either you just want one file, and you can run `bonobo init my-etl-job.py` (note the extension).
- Either you want a python package, and you can install `medikit` (`pip install medikit`), then run `bonobo init --package my_etl_pkg`.

I just updated the documentation on this regard at https://www.bonobo-project.org/how-to/bootstrap to describe the actual way of doing it, which should be much more straightforward than before.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. However, I wanted to obtain the .env and .gitignore files that the cookiecutter-bonobo template contained. Do you know how I can obtain these files?

Comment: The .env file was empty by default, so you should instead create one yourself and use it like described in http://docs.bonobo-project.org/en/master/guide/environment.html ; there is no requirement for this file to be called .env anymore, so you can name it anything you want.

The .gitignore file did only contain .env (see https://github.com/python-bonobo/cookiecutter-bonobo/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.name%7D%7D/.gitignore) so just create one to ignore your env vars file and you'll be good!